# How to display splash page every time the user access the apps in xcode?

Tags: xcode, splash-screen

For example, the splash name is default.png.
FYI- Application does not run in background is set to NO in plist.
Please do not ask me to set to 'NO' to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is for iOS, you can find many examples online...

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/06/22/creating-splash-screen-tutorial-for-iphone/

http://gigaom.com/apple/iphone-dev-sessions-making-a-splash-screen/